# White Screen of Death in Silex when switching from PHP 5.3 to Php 5.4 because of "session_start"

Tags: php, silex, php-5.4, wsod

Finally I was able to repro the issue with the following two lines:

```
session_set_save_handler(new SessionHandler());
session_start();
```

When I do this, I get a WSOD! Any idea why this happens?

============================================================

Finally, I digged deeper and deeper and narrowed it down to the issue being caused because of failure in `session_start()`; Still, I do not know why it fails that way.

So, the problem boils down to: 
When `session_start()` is called in `NativeSessionStorage::start()`, it fails. However, when I create a sample test page which just does `session_start()` it succeeds!

Does Silex do anything different?!

I am keeping the text below so that anyone facing similar issue understands the reason behind the failure.

============================================================

I have tried to switch from Php 5.3 to Php 5.4 recently and my website based on Silex stopped working with a WSOD.

I checked the PHP Error Logs and I see:
`Premature end of script headers: php54.cgi`

I tried doing a lot of stuff and finally thought of asking it online :(. Here's what I tried:

1. Created a bare bones Silex project and checked if it is working. Nope, it wasn't.
2. Added code before Silex is initialized and set `app[debug] = true` after:

   ```
   ini_set('display_errors', 1);
   error_reporting(-1);
   ErrorHandler::register();
   if ('cli' !== php_sapi_name()) {
       ExceptionHandler::register();
   }
   ```
3. Tried to check the extent to which the code goes. But I was keeping on stepping in. I went till `NativeSessionStorage::start()` and gave up, so it was working till then and any errors I generate there were being reported properly as expected.
4. Tried looking at other entries for how to fix BSOD, but none of them really explained how things would have changed by moving from PHP 5.3 to PHP 5.4! That is ALL I did. Just changed the PHP version and PHP.INI accordingly. Below is the PHP.INI I use now.

   ```
   ;                           |PIG v0.3.2.1|
   [PHP]
     open_basedir = 
     engine = 1
     zend.ze1_compatibility_mode = 
     short_open_tag = 1
     asp_tags = 
     precision = 14
     y2k_compliance = 1
     output_buffering = 4096
     zlib.output_compression = 
     implicit_flush = 
     unserialize_callback_func = 
     serialize_precision = 100
     allow_call_time_pass_reference = 
     safe_mode = 
     ; safe_mode_gid = 1
     safe_mode_include_dir = 
     safe_mode_exec_dir = 
     safe_mode_allowed_env_vars = "PHP_"
     safe_mode_protected_env_vars = "LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
     disable_functions = exec,passthru,shell_exec,system,proc_open,popen,show_source 
     disable_classes = 
     highlight.string = "#DD0000"
     highlight.comment = "#FF9900"
     highlight.keyword = "#007700"
     highlight.bg = "#FFFFFF"
     highlight.default = "#0000BB"
     highlight.html = "#000000"
     expose_php = 1
     max_execution_time = 30
     max_input_time = 60
     memory_limit = 128M
     error_reporting = 6135
     display_errors = 1
     display_startup_errors = 
     log_errors = 1
     log_errors_max_len = 1024
     ignore_repeated_errors = 
     ignore_repeated_source = 
     report_memleaks = 1
     track_errors = 
     html_errors = 
     error_log = "/hsphere/local/var/httpd/logs/php54_error.log"
     variables_order = EGPCS
     register_globals = 0
     ; register_long_arrays = 1
     register_argc_argv = 1
     auto_globals_jit = 1
     post_max_size = 30M
     ; magic_quotes_gpc = 1
     magic_quotes_runtime = 
     magic_quotes_sybase = 
     auto_prepend_file = 
     auto_append_file = 
     default_mimetype = "text/html"
     always_populate_raw_post_data = 1


   ;***** Added by go-pear
   include_path=".:/hsphere/shared/php54/include/php/PEAR"
   ;*****

     doc_root = 
     user_dir = 
     extension_dir = "/hsphere/shared/php54/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/"
     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
     file_uploads = 1
     upload_tmp_dir = 
     upload_max_filesize = 25M
     allow_url_fopen = 1
     allow_url_include = 
     default_socket_timeout = 60
     auto_detect_line_endings = 1
   [Syslog]
     define_syslog_variables = 
   [mail function]
     sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -fpostmaster@example.com
     mail.force_extra_parameters = 
   [SQL]
     sql.safe_mode = 
   [ODBC]
     odbc.allow_persistent = 
     odbc.check_persistent = 1
     odbc.max_persistent = "-1"
     odbc.max_links = "-1"
     odbc.defaultlrl = 4096
     odbc.defaultbinmode = 1
   [MySQL]
     mysql.allow_persistent = 
     mysql.max_persistent = "-1"
     mysql.max_links = "-1"
     mysql.default_port = 3306
     mysql.default_socket = "/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock"
     mysql.default_host = localhost
     mysql.default_user = 
     mysql.default_password = 
     mysql.connect_timeout = 60
     mysql.trace_mode = 
   [MySQLi]
     mysqli.max_links = "-1"
     mysqli.default_port = 3306
     mysqli.default_socket = "/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock"
     mysqli.default_host = localhost
     mysqli.default_user = 
     mysqli.default_pw = 
     mysqli.reconnect = 
   [PostgresSQL]
     pgsql.allow_persistent = 
     pgsql.auto_reset_persistent = 
     pgsql.max_persistent = "-1"
     pgsql.max_links = "-1"
     pgsql.ignore_notice = 0
     pgsql.log_notice = 0
   [dbx]
     dbx.colnames_case = lowercase
   [bcmath]
     bcmath.scale = 0
   [Session]
     session.save_handler = files
     session.save_path = "${US_ROOTF}/tmp"
     session.use_cookies = 1
     session.use_only_cookies = 1
     session.name = PHPSESSID
     session.auto_start = 0
     session.cookie_lifetime = 0
     session.cookie_path = /
     session.cookie_domain =
     session.cookie_httponly =
     session.serialize_handler = php
     session.gc_probability = 1
     session.gc_divisor = 1000
     session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
     session.bug_compat_42 = Off
     session.bug_compat_warn = Off
     session.referer_check =
     session.cache_limiter = nocache
     session.cache_expire = 180
     session.use_trans_sid = 0
     session.hash_function = 0
     session.hash_bits_per_character = 5
     url_rewriter.tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry"
   [Assertion]
     assert.active = 1
     assert.warning = 1
     assert.bail = 
     assert.callback = 0
     assert.quiet_eval = 0
   [Sockets]
     sockets.use_system_read = 1
   [mbstring]
     mbstring.language = Neutral
     mbstring.internal_encoding = "EUC-JP"
     mbstring.http_input = pass
     mbstring.http_output = pass
     mbstring.encoding_translation = 
     mbstring.detect_order = auto
     mbstring.substitute_character = 
     mbstring.func_overload = 0
   [exif]
     exif.encode_unicode = "ISO-8859-15"
     exif.decode_unicode_motorola = "UCS-2BE"
     exif.decode_unicode_intel = "UCS-2LE"
     exif.encode_jis = 
     exif.decode_jis_motorola = JIS
     exif.decode_jis_intel = JIS
   [soap]
     soap.wsdl_cache_enabled = 1
     soap.wsdl_cache_dir = "/tmp"
     soap.wsdl_cache_ttl = 86400
   [Zend]
   zend_extension="/hsphere/shared/php54/lib/php/extensions/ZendGuardLoader.so"
   ;  zend_extension_manager.optimizer = "/usr/local/Zend/lib/Optimizer-3.3.3"
   ;  zend_extension_manager.optimizer_ts = "/usr/local/Zend/lib/Optimizer_TS-3.3.3"
   ;  zend_optimizer.version = "3.3.3"
   ;  zend_extension = "/usr/local/Zend/lib/ZendExtensionManager.so"
   ;  zend_extension_ts = "/usr/local/Zend/lib/ZendExtensionManager_TS.so"
   [suhosin]
   ;  extension = suhosin.so
     suhosin.executor.include.max_traversal = 4
     suhosin.executor.disable_emodifier = 0
     suhosin.executor.include.whitelist = "http://,https://,file://,bfa://"
     suhosin.executor.allow_symlink = 0
     suhosin.mail.protect = 1
     suhosin.upload.disallow_elf = 1
     suhosin.log.syslog = 511
     suhosin.log.syslog.facility = 8
     suhosin.log.syslog.priority = 1
     suhosin.log.sapi = 511
     suhosin.session.encrypt = 0
     suhosin.cookie.cryptua = 0
     suhosin.session.cryptdocroot = 0
     suhosin.cookie.cryptdocroot = 0
     suhosin.executor.include.whitelist="phar"
     suhosin.get.max_value_length = 10240
   [curl]
   extension=curl.so
   [gmp]
   extension=gmp.so
   [iconv]
   extension=iconv.so
   [imap]
   extension=imap.so
   [mysqli]
   extension=mysqli.so
   [mysql]
   extension=mysql.so
   [odbc]
   extension=odbc.so
   [pdo]
   extension=pdo.so
   [pdo_mysql]
   extension=pdo_mysql.so
   [pdo_pgsql]
   extension=pdo_pgsql.so
   [pdo_sqlite]
   extension=pdo_sqlite.so
   [pgsql]
   extension=pgsql.so
   [sqlite3]
   extension=sqlite3.so
   [htscanner]
   extension=htscanner.so
   [mongo]
   extension=mongo.so
   [date]
   date.timezone=EST
   ```

I used the tools provided by the control panel of my hosting account to make the switch, so I am pretty sure it must be proper. I am able to run other PHP scripts.

Comment: have you checked the PHP log on the server to see what error it's getting?

Comment: Yes Barmar, I get: Premature end of script headers: php54.cgi. I have added it to the question so the others also know.

Comment: would this help? http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/web_servers.html

Comment: No @RST, the server configuration is right. And I cannot use the PHP 5.4 server for production or in a shared hosting environment :).

Comment: Looks like some issue with the SessionHandler for PHP 5.4! When I use the NullSessionHandler provided by Silex, I do not see any WSOD. Currently, I do not need any sessions, so just doing with that :).

Comment: When things break at session_start it could be related to either the storage area (be it file system or db) or white-space in the scripts that is output before the session starts.  So you could try looking at the session save path and make sure your cgi has permissions to write to it and everything is ok there (or check the table is OK if using a db).  You could also check to see if any headers have already been sent prior to session_start, just in case.

Answer (score 1):

I think I had the same problem before. If you are using PHP Version < 5.4.11 - there is a bug in the SessionHandler implementation - check this [link](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5868) out, maybe it is somehow related...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps run 'strace' to see where PHP is failing.  Perhaps you have permissions issues based on what user is trying to access certain resources.  For example the directory where sessions are supposed to be saved.